# Java Swing: Action Event to submit multiple variables

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jbutton

I'm creating an simple application that let's me search for an employee's information so far I can search for the first name but I want to add more variables to the search like Date of Birth, Address, Profession etc which is submitted by a single action event on a **JButton**.

How would I go about doing this? I've looked into using IF Else and Switch statement but I don't have a clue how to go forwards.

```
 private void searchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     String val1 = textFirstName.getText();       

     try {
          String sql = "select * from employees where first_name = '"+val1+"'";
          stmt = con.createStatement();
          rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          dataTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }

     catch ( SQLException err ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Appointments.this, err.getMessage());

   }

}
```

Comment: Please include a small amount of code to show your problem and ideally what have you tried.

Comment: ok have done, within the method i just want to be able to search multiple variables and be able to submit it with a single JButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do would be to create a dynamic panel which would grow as users add more search options. Essentially, you would have an *Add Search Term* button which would add a new combo box and text field each time it is pressed (provided that, for instance, the last combo box in the list is not empty).

You would need to create a class of the sort:

```
public class SearchTerm {
    private int id;
    private String column;
    private String value;

    //Getters and setters and the rest.
    ...
}
```

Once that you create the combo box (which will contain all the fields which the users can search through) and text box, which will contain the text, you could add a new `SearchTerm` object to your list of search terms. The `Id` field would come in handy should you wish to allow users to remove and/or change existing search terms.

The next step would be to create a separate layer which essentially does the searching. This would make your UI layer contain UI functionality. The Single Responsibility pattern dictates that a class do only one thing. Currently, your class is responsible for UI and DB operations.

This new layer will have a method which takes in a List of `SearchTerm` items. From there you would construct your search query by iterating over the `SearchTerm` objects provided and their corresponding values. Once done, you could return a list of `User` objects which resemble the data in your database. All this would need to execute on a separate thread. You will need to look into background workers for this.

Some additional points:

1. Please make sure you use prepared statements instead of SQL concatenation. As is, your application is prone to SQL injection.
2. At the moment, you are performing your search operation on the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). This is not recommended since this thread is responsible for maintaining the UI. Thus, if you do any intensive operations on this thread, the UI will suffer (by becoming less responsive or plain freezing). Launching your search operation on a separate thread will ensure that the EDT will not be bogged down by non UI related operations. You could then update the UI from the background thread through the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` mechanism.